# How to dynamically add a TaxonomyFieldControl to a page?

Tags: 2010, visual-studio, taxonomy

I had gone the route of creating a placeholder on the aspx page and then doing:

```
myPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(myTaxonomyControl);
```

but for some reason this doesn't do anything.  No error and no control.  Do I need to do anything special to add this type of control to a page?

Answer (score 1):

This is the code I use:

```
var taxField = field as TaxonomyField; // the SPField the control should bind to
var session = new TaxonomySession(field.ParentList.ParentWeb.Site);
var store = session.TermStores[0];
var termSet = store.GetTermSet(taxField.TermSetId);
var taxonomyControl = new TaxonomyWebTaggingControl();
taxonomyControl.IsMulti = taxField.AllowMultipleValues;
taxonomyControl.IsAddTerms = termSet.IsOpenForTermCreation;
if (termSet.IsOpenForTermCreation)
{
  taxonomyControl.AllowFillIn = true;
}
taxonomyControl.TermSetId.Add(store.Id);
taxonomyControl.ID = "fld_" + taxField.InternalName;
taxonomyControl.FieldName = taxField.Title;
taxonomyControl.FieldId = taxField.Id.ToString();
taxonomyControl.SSPList = taxField.SspId.ToString();
taxonomyControl.AnchorId = taxField.AnchorId;
taxonomyControl.TermSetList = taxField.TermSetId.ToString();
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
{
  if (Item[taxField.InternalName] != null)
  {
    taxonomyControl.Text = Item[taxField.InternalName].ToString();
  }
}
fieldPanel.Controls.Add(taxonomyControl);
```

Comment: Where do you create the `field`? Some code seems to be missing

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind the term set to the TaxonomyWebTaggingControl so that it allows you to pick and display terms. See link below:

http://blog.bugrapostaci.com/2010/09/23/taxonomywebtaggingcontrol-sharepoint/

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.taxonomy.taxonomywebtaggingcontrol.aspx